# Disable Sublime Text 2 "Smart-Switching" On Close Tab

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When a tab is closed in Sublime Text 2, ST2 switches to the most recently accessed file. Is it possible to disable this behavior, so ST2 will instead switch to the next tab to the left or right? This is how Chrome, for example, behaves. When closing large batches of files, I find remembering what file is going to be selected next very tricky.

To clarify: Try opening five tabs. Select tab 5, then tab 3, then tab 5 again. Close tab 5. You'll be switched to tab 3 (the next-most-recent tab) rather than tab 4 (the nearest tab).

I'm on OS X Mavericks, on the off chance that's relevant, and ST2 2.0.2, Build 2221.

Comment: You might be able to achieve this with either a recorded macro, or by creating a plug-in per http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/plugins.html. No promises, but maybe worth investigating those options if the current behavior bugs you that much.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime 3 does not have the behavior and there is also a plugin for it called [TabsExtra](https://github.com/facelessuser/TabsExtra) that lets you change the behavior of closing tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Like in Chrome, you can use cmd-alt-right/leftarrow, or cmd-number to pick a specific tab.

Comment: I use those options to switch tabs, but the question is about closing tabs. To see what I'm describing, try opening five tabs. Select tab 5, then tab 3, then tab 5 again. Close tab 5. You'll be switched to tab 3, rather than the nearest tab (tab 4).